# What is this connector on the rear bumper?

Tags: chevrolet, truck, connector, colorado

This is a picture of the rear bumper of a 2016 Chevy Colorado:

[image: rear bumper picture]

On the left is a harness for 4- and 7-pin trailer connectors. In the center is the license plate (blurred).

What is the circular connector on the right? If I pop open the cover I see the inside of a hollow tube with no wires that leads toward the front of the vehicle.

I searched through the truck's manual, paying close attention to the section on trailers and towing, but found no reference to this port.

What is the purpose of the round port on the right?

Comment: Where does the hollow tube go?

Comment: @tlhIngan I don't know, I could only follow it so far before it was covered by other stuff (like the spare tire).

Comment: It's FOR the spare tire. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the access port for the tire iron so you can lower the spare tire from under the truck. Look at your Owner's Manual under "Vehicle Care," it will show you where on the truck to find your tire changing tool kit and how to use it to lower the spare tire.

Comment: I finally had time to confirm this. It was a hike through the owner's manual, too: there were at least four sections that mentioned the spare tire, but only one had the diagram showing the rod to unlock the spare tire via that port. Thanks!